# zoom in / out the image inside a pictureBox in VC++2015 (OpenCV used)

Tags: visual-c++

OS : Win 10

IDE: Visual Studio 2015

Language: C++

Others: I use OpenCV 3.4

I just create a Window Form using CLR empty project,
then put on a pictureBox & three buttons.

First button: load a local image and show on the pictureBox:

```
pictureBox1->Image = Image::FromFile("D:/something.png");
global_mat = imread("D:/something.png", 1); // global_mat is a global Mat.
zoom_in_counter = 0; // zoom_in_counter is a global int.
```

Second button: zoom in the image in the pictureBox

```
    if (zoom_in_counter < 5) // You can only enlarge the image 5 times.
    {
        Mat new_mat = Mat::zeros(0, 0, CV_8UC3);
        resize(global_mat, new_mat, cv::Size(global_mat.cols * 2, global_mat.rows * 2));
        global_mat = new_mat;

        if ((pictureBox1->Width != new_mat.cols) || (pictureBox1->Height != new_mat.rows))
        {
            pictureBox1->Width = new_mat.cols;
            pictureBox1->Height = new_mat.rows;
            pictureBox1->Image = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(new_mat.cols, new_mat.rows);
        }

        System::Drawing::Bitmap^ bmpImage = gcnew Bitmap(
            new_mat.cols, new_mat.rows, new_mat.step,
            System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb,
            System::IntPtr(new_mat.data)
        );

        Graphics^ g = Graphics::FromImage(pictureBox1->Image);

        g->DrawImage(bmpImage, 0, 0, new_mat.cols, new_mat.rows);
        pictureBox1->Refresh();

        delete g;

        zoom_in_counter++;
    }
```

Third buttin: zoom out the image in the pictureBox

```
    if (zoom_in_counter > 0) // You can't shrink the image.
    {
        Mat new_mat = Mat::zeros(0, 0, CV_8UC3);
        resize(global_mat, new_mat, cv::Size(global_mat.cols * 0.5, global_mat.rows * 0.5));
        global_mat = new_mat;

        if ((pictureBox1->Width != new_mat.cols) || (pictureBox1->Height != new_mat.rows))
        {
            pictureBox1->Width = new_mat.cols;
            pictureBox1->Height = new_mat.rows;
            pictureBox1->Image = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(new_mat.cols, new_mat.rows);
        }

        System::Drawing::Bitmap^ bmpImage = gcnew Bitmap(
            new_mat.cols, new_mat.rows, new_mat.step,
            System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb,
            System::IntPtr(new_mat.data)
        );

        Graphics^ g = Graphics::FromImage(pictureBox1->Image);

        g->DrawImage(bmpImage, 0, 0, new_mat.cols, new_mat.rows);
        pictureBox1->Refresh();

        delete g;

        zoom_in_counter--;
    }
```

And then,
every I zoom in or zoom out, it works,
excludeingthe image is zoomed back to the original size.

I'll get such error message:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

It's really odd!

Comment: `Graphics^ g` -- That's not C++.  Know your tools and tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Thanks PaulMcKenzie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, my friend figure out what's wrong,

please refer to:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/windows/desktop/ms536315(v=vs.85).aspx

stride [in]
Type: INT

Integer that specifies the byte offset between the beginning of one scan line and the next. This is usually (but not necessarily) the number of bytes in the pixel format (for example, 2 for 16 bits per pixel) multiplied by the width of the bitmap. **The value passed to this parameter must be a multiple of four.**